# Can I play PUBG on Remix OS?

Tags: android, pubg-battlegrounds

Is there any special task needed to run PUBG on RemixOS Android 6.0? I've downloaded and installed PUBG on RemixOS but after Tencent logo, a just black screen is coming. I've also installed Google Play Games properly on RemixOS.
Is something missing?

Comment: There is also an official emulator for PUBG Mobile, from the developers themselves, Tencent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RemixOS is meant to be use in multiple computers, it does not have 3D rendering on non-Intel GPUs. A quote from [the issue tracker](https://github.com/JideTechnology/Remix-OS-For-PC/issues/51):

> Currently Remix OS has poor GPU support for non-Intel chips so in case if system can't load dedicated GPU driver, system will load in software rendering mode (handled by CPU - lower performance).

When you try to play games that require hardware for 3D rendering, you will get a black screen ([Asphalt 8](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftA8HM)) or a complete crash (aka `<app> has stopped working`).

Please note that this happens on both [Remix OS PC](http://www.jide.com/remixos) and [Remix OS Player](http://www.jide.com/remixos-player).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Found an alternative that works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHOENIX OS. It's an alternative Android Emulator for Windows (like Remix OS).

I've been playing PUBG on a low-spec machine with 65-100 fps.